# Pandas resampling time series with given start and end dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe `df1` with sparse dates as index and two columns. I want to generate a new dataframe `df2` with sampled date (each hour) between given start and end dates containing the `df1` values.

Here is `df1`:

```
df1:
                     col1   col2
2019-01-01 07:12:00     1      0
2019-01-01 10:25:00     0      1
```

Here is what should be `df2` starting and `00:00:00` and finishing at `12:00:00` on `2019-01-01` with a sampling of one hour:

```
df2:
                     col1   col2
2019-01-01 00:00:00     0      0
2019-01-01 01:00:00     0      0
2019-01-01 02:00:00     0      0
2019-01-01 03:00:00     0      0
2019-01-01 04:00:00     0      0
2019-01-01 05:00:00     0      0
2019-01-01 06:00:00     0      0
2019-01-01 07:00:00     1      0
2019-01-01 08:00:00     0      0
2019-01-01 09:00:00     0      0
2019-01-01 10:00:00     0      1
2019-01-01 11:00:00     0      0
2019-01-01 12:00:00     0      0
```

I tried using pandas dataframe `resample()` function but did not succeed pecifying start and end dates.

Comment: use `pandas.interpolate`

Comment: @has how to use it ? I don't see any arguments to specify start and end dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.interpolate`. Following are the steps you should do.

1) Create a list of timestamps where you want to interpolate new data.

2) Append this list of timestamp to dataframe index. In this way, dataframe will have all the required indexes but the `column values` will be `NAN`.

3) Sort the dataframe with index

4) call `pandas.interpolate` method to fill the values in between. You can choose different parameters like type of interpolation in this method. For more detail look in the documentation